# Wordpress wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, функции, navigationbar

Доброго времени суток.
В WP у wp_nav_menu() есть параметры

```
            <?php wp_nav_menu( array(
            'theme_location'  => '',
            'menu'            => 'top_menu',
            'container'       => 'nav',
            'container_class' => 'navbar navbar-default',
            'container_id'    => '',
            'menu_class'      => 'nav navbar-nav',
            'menu_id'         => '',
            'echo'            => true,
            'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
            'before'          => '',
            'after'           => '',
            'link_before'     => '',
            'link_after'      => '',
            'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            'depth'           => 0
        ));
```

И я никак не могу понять принцип в items_wrap.
Объясните доступно что за звери %1$s и тд, или ссылку полезную по этому вопросу

И еще на выходе имеем 
[image: screenshot]

Вывод такого количества классов у li зависит от item_wrap?
Если нет, то где изменить набор классов? Я не вижу смысла в 3 трех классах одинаковых для всех элементов, может у них есть предназначение, если меню многоуровневое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вовсе не звери, в `%1$s` число после `%` указыват на порядок вывода, а `s` после доллара - соответсвтует `string` т.е. вставить, как строку.

```
$format = 'На %2$s сидят %1$d обезьян';
echo sprintf($format, $num, $location);
```

Пример из [документации](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php), думаю тут очевидно, `$num` заменит `%1$d`, a `$location` - `%2$s`

Это все параметры функции [sprintf](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sprintf.php), которая используется не строке 403 функции [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) <- a вот и полезная ссылка, внизу есть source code самой функции, а в комментариях несколько способов изменить классы у `<li>`, т.к. да, действительно, сам wp делает вот что: "The following classes are applied to menu items" и дальше огромный список классов.

Лично я, в свое время в похожей ситуации использовал способ с собственной функцией и добавлением фильтра `add_filter`

Comment: Спасибо за 'echo'=> FALSE - а то думал как его прочитать, но не выводить!